# Copy Linux files to another location

Tags: linux, rhel

We have a linux server and for some transactions it is keeping the log files only for the last 10 days. After than the file gets deleted. I want to copy these files to another location using a script. I searched google but couldn't satisfactory result. I'm new to Linux also.

Can someone please guide me if this can be achieved and how ?

Comment: Generally you use Linux cron to schedule regular task. 
About archiving logs, you can do a cron task that does the copy or the move operation but you can also take advantage of tools as logrotate.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the previous answer by nissim abehcera in a sh script:

```
cp -R SOURCE_DIRECTORY  DESTINATION_DIRECTORY
```

Just paste the bash commands in a text file, name it file.sh and make sure it is executable:

```
chmod +x file.sh
```

You can just run the script and it will do whatever you wrote in there.